# jQuery selecting a non-fixed sibling of a parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I'm trying to use jQuery to select an element like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>First item</li>
        <li>Second item</li>
        <li>Third item</li>
    <ul>
</div>
<div>Item to be operated on when the first li is clicked.</div>
<div>Item to be operated on when the second li is clicked.</div>
<div>Item to be operated on when the third li is clicked.</div>
```

And of course I'm looking to start my jQuery function with

```
$('ul li')
```

Is there a way to do this without multiple dom dives?  What I essentially need is "next().next().next()" if it didn't only operate on direct siblings.  Assume I can't move around the markup.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you might do :

```
$('div').eq($(this).index()+1);
```

See [the eq function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.index()` to select the corresponding `div` element:

```
var $divs = $('div');

$('ul li').click(function() {
    var $div = $divs.eq($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

Comment: needs the `index() + 1`, the list is contained within a `div` as well

Comment: @billyonecan: This HTML needs some classes. Thanks, I'll add that in.